# Can I put Ignite UI scripts at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, infragistics, ignite-ui

The [Ignite UI boilerplate](http://www.igniteui.com/getting-started#helpJquiCodeExamplEsIgnIteUiBoilerplateJqueryUiFullHtml) has all the JavaScript files loaded at the top of the page. This is consistent with [every](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2012.2/ui.iggrid) [other](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2012.2/ui.iggridpaging) [example](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/jQuery/2012.2/CLR4.0?page=igGrid_Overview.html) I can find on the Infragistics site.

I'd like to load these files at the bottom of the page instead. However, when I try to do that I get a JavaScript error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

On the view, I use the Grid HTML helper like so (simplified):

```
@model IQueryable<Product>

@( Html.Infragistics().Grid( Model ).DataBind().Render() )
```

This produces the following output on the page:

```
<table id="Grid1"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () {$('#Grid1').igGrid({ ... });</script>
```

If I could just tell Infragistics to put the `script` tag at the bottom of the page, after I load jQuery, jQuery UI, etc., everything would be peachy. Is there a way I can do this and still use the HTML helpers?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer JavaScript resources using Infragistics Loader.

In CSHTML you will have :

```
<script src="Scripts/infragistics.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in another script tag you will have the following :

```
$.ig.loader({
scriptPath: '{IG Resources root}/js/',
cssPath: '{IG Resources root}/css/'}); 

$.ig.loader('igGrid.Paging.Updating', 
     function () {
     // Create a couple of igGrids 
        $("#grid1").igGrid({
        virtualization: false,
        autoGenerateColumns: true,
        jQueryTemplating: false,
     // and other}
```

Read more about this here : http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/Deployment_Guide_JavaScript_Resources.html#referencing_resources

Comment: This is assuming I will not be using the HTML helpers though, right?